# Help with file permissions in Unix

Tags: unix, permissions

I have given a text file in my home directory the permissions 644. Another user logged into the same machine cannot read or copy my file. Why is this?

Comment: What is the message the other user see?

Comment: This isn't exactly a programming question. Try http://linux.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Does he have access to the directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably because the group lacks (read and) execute permissions on the parent directory/directories.

E.g.

```
mkdir /tmp/secret
chmod 600 /tmp/secret
touch /tmp/secret/publicfile
chmod 644 /tmp/secret/publicfile
```

/tmp/secret/publicfile will not be accessible to group members.

There are also POSIX ACLs and or xattrs (extended attributes) that might be interfering. Besides that only AppArmor, SELinux policies come to mind.

Oh and group membership becomes active on the next login (so if users were *recently* added to the particular group, they might just need to relogin)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you mean the privileges not the mask.
644 means that this user can write and execute, but cannot read nor copy. You could try 655 which means: other users can read and execute my file.

Comment: 644 means the owner can read and write, and everyone else can only read; it doesn't grant execute permission to anyone.  655 doesn't make much sense; it grants execute permission to everyone *except* the owner.  If you want to grant execute permission, you should use 755 -- but don't do that unless the file should actually be executable.  But yes, "mask" is the wrong concept (it applies to `chmod`).

Comment: very confusing: who is 'this user'? why would group members have execute permissions that the owner doesn't himself have? Anyway, With 644 all users can read (hence copy).